# How to replace uri in Symfony 2.1 before initialize controller

Tags: events, symfony, kernel

I want replace uri before started system.

I have routing collection:

/service-actions/{serviceId}/{actionPath}

Request: http://domain.com/service-actions/1/iframe

I want replace full uri:

```
http://s{serviceId}.domain.com/{actionPath}
```

http://s1.domain.com/iframe

**I try:**
Create a new event listener on kernel request, but in event not replace request.

Comment: You should use apache rewrite rules http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: This is not an option, since it is necessary to configure config.yml